# Is it possible (and how) to make an RDOMail object wrap a MAPI IMessage object?

Tags: mapi, outlook-redemption

I am working to create a plugin for some application using C++. The application would provide me MAPI messages and gives me a chance to work on them. The application gives me the MAPI messages as pointers to the [IMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842097.aspx) interface.

I am used to working with MAPI messages using the [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) library mainly with C#. But in this case, I always get an `RDOMail` object when I open messages (not `IMessage` objects).

I was wondering if it is possible to use the `RDOMail` object in Outlook Redemption to wrap an existing message that I have a pointer to (the `IMessage` object).

The `RDOMail` interface has a `MAPIOBJECT` property that returns the underlying MAPI object. However, this property is read-only.

Is there a way to wrap a MAPI message using Outlook Redemption using the `IMessage` pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can pass IMessage interface to RDOSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject.